# Как узнать голосовал ли пользователь Rails (гем acts_votable)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, есть такое условие:

```
  - if user_signed_in?
    - if current_user.voted_for? answer and answer.liked_by current_user
      = link_to unlike_answer_path(answer), class: "unlike", remote: true, method: :put do
        button.btn.btn-info aria-label=("Left Align") type="button"
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-down.glyphicon-align-center aria-hidden="true"
          span.badge  id="badge_downvote_value" = answer.get_downvotes.size
    - elsif current_user.voted_for? answer and answer.disliked_by current_user
      = link_to like_answer_path(answer),  class: "like", remote: true,  method: :put do
        button.btn.btn-info aria-label=("Left Align") type="button"
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-up.glyphicon-align-center aria-hidden="true"
          span.badge id="badge_upvote_value" = answer.get_upvotes.size
```

Сначала я проверяю или вошел пользователь, а потом если он проголосовал и лайкнул ответ - прячу кнопку like и отображаю кнопку dislike, иначе наоборот - прячу кнопку dislike и отображаю кнопку для like. 
НО по не понятным мне причинам постоянно отображается только кнопка dislike. причем она не работает. То есть при попытке поставить dislike ничего не происходит.. Если условия убрать и оставить просто 2 кнопки, то все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил заменив сторку

```
- if current_user.voted_for? answer and answer.liked_by current_user
```

на

```
- if current_user.voted_up_on? answer
```